# Possible to run a single stage of my pipeline on a schedule?

Tags: gitlab-ci

I'm pretty new to Gitlab CI  and haven't been able to find an answer for this yet. I have my basic pipeline that runs unit tests, does some DB checks, builds an image, deploys to QA, runs some functional tests then deploys to production.

This codebase doesn't change much so we don't run tests every day / week but changes from other teams can affect this project.

Is it possible to just run the functional test stage of the pipeline on a schedule without rebuilding and deploying to QA? All of those steps before the test run require manual approval so even if we did just deploy to QA every day it would still require manual interaction.

Answer (score 0):

i think to understand that you want to run pipeline based on a schedule and not only pushing new code or launching it manually.

You can do that trought [Pipeline schedules](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/schedules.html), in the [Cofiguring Piepeline Schedules](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/schedules.html#configuring-pipeline-schedules) you can set when run your pipe and on which branch/tag.

[image]

Hope it was helpful!